# np.savetxt tab delimited txt file

Tags: python, numpy, save, txt

I have a dataframe that needs be txt file. So, I use `np.savetxt` method. However, dataframe consists of four columns which are string, string, string and integer, respectively.

`np.savetxt` takes `fmt` and `delimiter` parameters. In official document, it is said that `multi-format string, e.g. ‘Iteration %d – %10.5f’, in which case delimiter is ignored`

How can I use `fmt` for both specifying the columns' data types and for tab delimiter?

```
fmt = ('%s %s %s %d')

np.savetxt("test.txt", df, fmt=fmt)
```

Sample data:

```
DTL 3E046ZM/A 190198848376 0
DTL 3E047ZM/A 190198848406 0
DTL 3E309ZM/A 190198937339 0
```

I tried `('%s \t %s \t %s \t %d')` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You said you use dataframes, so pandas is is involved right?

Why then not just use it directly?:

```
df.to_csv('your_file.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
```

this will format the output according to the datatype the columns had in the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you Andreas! However, after converting txt, there are several steps. If I changed the savetxt to to_csv, I will need to change a lot of things in my code. But your solution will definetely work!

Answer (score 1):

As [`numpy.savetxt` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) informs you, you might provide *sequence of formats* e.g. `list` of `str`s as `fmt`, consider following simple example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,"Hello"],[4,5,6,"World"]])
fmt = ["%d","%d","%d","%s"]
np.savetxt("test.tsv", df, fmt=fmt, delimiter="\t")
```

creates `test.tsv` with following content

```
1   2   3   Hello
4   5   6   World
```